# Progress bar in Android not getting display after click anywhere on the page

Tags: android, webview

I am having one webview and one button in my android app.
I am showing ProgressDialog and disabling the click of button on onPageStarted function like :

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
{


                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    Dialog.show();
                    button1.setClickable(false);

}
```

and disabling the progress bar on onPageFinished and enabling the button

```
  public void  onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
                        if(Dialog.isShowing())
                                        {
                                                    Dialog.dismiss();
                                        }

                        button1.setClickable(true);

    }
```

but my problem is when i clicked on the button.Even if it is not clickable or clicked anywhere on the page the progress bar is  getting hidden which was properly displaying on show function and after the webpage is loaded in the webview.the button become clickable.How to display continue progress bar untill onPageFinished is called after loading of url

Comment: show your dialog code.

Comment: it's a standard progress bar                                     private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you check this Dialogs guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Second, that's because your dialog is not modal.
If you want to avoid that your user cancel the dialog clicking outside of it or clicking the back button you have to do:

[dialog.setCancelable( false );](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the dialog from `dismiss/close` from outside touch then you should do the following..

```
 ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
 Dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: @iRunner don't wanna prevent to get dismissed from outside touch?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

that won't close the progress dialog once click outside of it.